# Multiple SSRS Instances - how to query configuration details?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

We have about 20 SSRS Instances on one server.  I am hoping the configuration details are available through some kind of query or command line prompt.  I'm looking for all the pertinent info from the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, such as:

- Instance Name
- Report Server Virtual Directory
- Report Manager Virtual Directory
- Database Name

Hopefully the answer to this is available for both SQL Server 2005 and 2008R2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SSRS instance information can be obtained using WMI (see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152836(v=sql.105).aspx ) Easiest way to try it out is probably to use PowerShell. Here is some example for 2008R2 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgalla/archive/2010/05/26/rs-powershell-gems-the-wmi-provider.aspx
It should also work for 2005 if you change v10 to v9